# pulling data from data frame in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

I'm trying to create a vector using data from my data frame which contains all of the numeric values in the data frame.

Basically, I want a vector that has `(2,2,5,2,2,3,2,3,2,2,2,2,2)`.

```
two three   four    five    six seven
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  5   NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  3   NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

Comment: If you want to replicate your *exact* output, you could try `indx <- which(!is.na(data), arr.ind = TRUE) ;
data[indx[order(indx[, 1]), ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subset the dataframe for non-NA values with `!is.na(df)`:

```
df <- data.frame(two = c(2, 2, NA),
                 three = c(NA, NA, NA),
                 four = c(NA, 3, NA))
df
#   two three four
# 1   2    NA   NA
# 2   2    NA    3
# 3  NA    NA   NA

is.na(df)
#        two three  four
# [1,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
# [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
# [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE

df[!is.na(df)]
# [1] 2 2 3
```